# File permission in git

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio

I run git repository with visual studio. I create website using MVC. How can I share source with my teammate but he can only read and write View folder not other file? It is important that he can't copy or change other file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Git central repository you are using, you might have some options for setting permissions on specific branches which could be a way to control this.

However, in general Git terms, your teammate should only have read-only access to your central repository.  You can then use either branch or fork methodology with pull-requests to only allow changes you approve, back into the main repository.

Comment: I use visualstudio.com server and visual studio for manage my code and git.

Comment: It looks like you can control branch permissions.  See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-permissions.  If you aren't overly familiar with using branches, there is some good info here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/git-branching-guidance.  I also like the Atlassian Git tutorials which are somewhat generic Git examples on branching strategies etc: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials.